# Remote control of third PC via video-conference?

Tags: windows, mouse, webcam, remote-control, conferencing

I have a PC which controls a fabrication machine.
On this machine-PC, no additional software can be installed and it cannot be connected to the internet.
So, there is no way to install TeamViewer or something like that.
Nevertheless, I would like to control this PC remotely.

The remote control is basically limited to check the current screen and make a few mouse clicks here and there remotely.
There are no time critical steps.
If the keyboard could also be accessed this would be a nice add-on.

So, getting the content of the PC screen seems to be relatively easy:
I place a laptop with internet access next to the machine-PC and position a webcam to the machine-PC's monitor and start a web-conference.

So, but now, how could I remotely control the machine-PC's mouse?

My first simple idea would be an actuator/robot which is controlled by the laptop next to the machine-PC to mechanically move the mouse. This laptop in turn is controlled by a third computer, e.g. from my home via a web-conference, e.g. Teams, Zoom, or whatever. Preferred operation system would be Windows.

Are there maybe any smarter and/or already existing solutions? Any ideas, concerns, suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Network KVM devices can do display capture and act as a keyboard and mouse for a device: https://www.kvmswitchdirect.co.uk/acatalog/Remote_access_products.html

Comment: https://pikvm.org/ or [TinyPilot Voyager](https://tinypilotkvm.com/product/tinypilot-voyager2a) see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TIrkEr2AeDY

Comment: "no additional software can be installed" - does that include portable software that doesn't need installation?

Comment: @Mokubai thanks for this hint. I will check it in more detail.

Comment: @Gantendo thank you for the links. "...Plug&Play no software installation required..." Sounds good. I will check in more detail.

Comment: @harrymc well, let's assume (in worst case) the machine PC has some very old OP system, e.g. Win95, WinXP, OS/2 or other special ones. In these cases maybe the sugggested KVM devices might even not work. Therefore, ideally, it would be good if you need not to touch the system, In any case I don't want to mess up that PC. But do you maybe have a suggestion for a portable software (e.g. for Win7SP1, not that "old" though ;-)

Comment: I haven't used the TinyPilot (yet). If you use the PiKVM with Tailscale then you must remember to disable key expiry https://tailscale.com/kb/1028/key-expiry/ (yes, I was stupid)

Comment: Does this old machine have any LAN capabilities ?

Comment: @harrymc Maybe, but don't know yet. I need to check next week. The machine-PC is in the lab and outside in the office is a second monitor (via cable) and a USB cable with a second mouse and keyboard. So, I can control the machine from the office. But additionally, I want to control it from home. As I understand KVM devices are exactly made for that. But if possible without expensive mobile abonnements for high data volumes. If possible via simple video-conference and maybe a "specially modified" mouse device in the office.